# How can I convert MultiMap<Integer, Foo> to Map<Integer, Set<Foo>> using Guava?

Tags: java, set, guava

I'm using MultiMap from Google Guava 12 like this:

```
Multimap<Integer, OccupancyType> pkgPOP = HashMultimap.create();
```

after inserting values into this multimap, I need to return:

```
Map<Integer, Set<OccupancyType>>
```

However, when I do:

```
return pkgPOP.asMap();
```

It returns me

```
Map<Integer, Collection<OccupancyType>>
```

How can I return `Map<Integer, Set<OccupancyType>>` instead ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Look at [this issue and comment #2 by Kevin Bourrillion](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/issues/detail?id=118#c2), head Guava dev:

> You can double-cast the `Map<K, Collection<V>>` first to a raw Map and
>   then to the `Map<K, Set<V>>` that you want. You'll have to suppress an
>   unchecked warning and you should comment at that point, *"Safe because
>   SetMultimap guarantees this."* I may even update the SetMultimap
>   javadoc to mention this trick.

So do unchecked cast:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Safe because SetMultimap guarantees this.
final Map<Integer, Set<OccupancyType>> mapOfSets = 
    (Map<Integer, Set<OccupancyType>>) (Map<?, ?>) pkgPOP.asMap();
```

**EDIT:**

Since Guava 15.0 you can use [helper method](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#asMap-com.google.common.collect.SetMultimap-) to do this in more elegant way:

```
Map<Integer, Set<OccupancyType>> mapOfSets = Multimaps.asMap(pkgPOP);
```

Comment: I was sure that the rightmost cast had to be to plain `Map`, but maybe that was due to a version of javac that we don't care about anymore... not sure.

Answer (score 10):

Guava contributor here:

Do the unsafe cast.  It'll be safe.

It can't return a `Map<K, Set<V>>` because of the way Java inheritance works.  Essentially, the `Multimap` supertype has to return a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`, and because `Map<K, Set<V>>` isn't a subtype of `Map<K, Collection<V>>`, you can't override `asMap()` to return a `Map<K, Set<V>>`.

Comment: Louis, you don't sleep at all, do you? ;)

Comment: Does it matter what implementation I use for (Set)MultiMap ? (in my case, I'm using HashMultiMap). Will all hell break loose if I use something like this: `SetMultiMap mapOfSets = LinkedListMultiMap.create()`

Comment: Well, `LinkedListMultimap` is a `ListMultimap`, not a `SetMultimap`.  As long as you use _some_ `SetMultimap` implementation, e.g. `LinkedHashMultimap` or `TreeMultimap`, you're fine.  (And @Xaerxess, I'm on UK time for the duration of the summer.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thanks! Both your and Xaerxess reply are good as answers for me.