# Use guava to map collection to id

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, guava

I can do this :

```
Map<Long, MyBean> mappedbean = Maps.uniqueIndex(myBeanList, toId);
```

where

```
private final Function<BeanWithId, Long> toId=
            new Function<BeanWithId, Long>() {
                public Long apply(BeanWithId beanWithId) {
                    return beanWithId.getId();
                }
            };
```

But how do I create a map of sublists, so something like this :

```
Map<Long, List<MyBean>> mappedbean = Maps.somethingSomething(myBeanList, toId);
```

where the id is not a **unique** identifier on the bean.

A boring old **for loop** ?

Comment: A "boring old" for loop is frequently more direct and readable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use Guava for this, but the `Stream` API of Java 8:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;

final Map<Long, List<MyBean>> mappedbean = myBeanList.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(MyBean::getId));
```

With Guava, you can do:

```
final Map<Long, Collection<MyBean>> mappedbean = Multimaps.index(myBeanList, toId).asMap();
```

Although `Multimaps.index` returns an `ImmutableListMultimap`, from the [documentation for `ListMultiMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html#asMap%28%29):

> The returned map's values are guaranteed to be of type List. To obtain this map with the more specific generic type `Map<K, List<V>>`, call `Multimaps.asMap(ListMultimap)` instead.

So a cast to `Map<Long, List>` would always be safe, and in fact you can do:

```
final Map<Long, List<MyBean>> mappedbean = Multimaps.asMap(Multimaps.index(myBeanList, toId));
```

To get the exact type you want. (Thanks to [@Xaerxess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534832/use-guava-to-map-collection-to-id/29534940#comment47223128_29534940) for the hint)

Comment: thanks, but I am stuck with Java 1.6 and guava 11 :-(

Comment: @NimChimpsky apparently `Multimaps.index` is [since 2.0](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider The cast to `Map<Long, List<MyBean>>` is safe, since it's guaranteed by [`ListMultimap#asMap` contract](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html#asMap%28%29). You can also use [`Multimaps#asMap(ListMultimap)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#asMap%28com.google.common.collect.ListMultimap%29) helper here.

Comment: @NimChimpsky So [do the (safe) cast explicitely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204143/how-can-i-convert-multimapinteger-foo-to-mapinteger-setfoo-using-guava/11205178#11205178).

Comment: @Xaerxess actually I just changed the type I required to Collection, don't like casting